# C# getting a selected date from calendar and displaying it in a message box

Tags: c#, calendar

C# getting a selected date from calendar and displaying it in a message box, the data will later be used to in an email that will be automatically generated.

I'm using a standard Month calendar in visual studios 2012, and I would like the date selected by the user to be displayed with the rest of my data in a message box, however I'm finding it hard to pull through just the selected date and not the whole date range.

I'm extremely knew to C# and am currently learning it at college however this isn't covered in my course :S.

This is what I have so far:

```
    //Calendar
    private void completionCalendar_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
    {

    }



//Button
        private void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
//pretty sure the maxselectioncount is in the wrong place 

        completionCalendar.MaxSelectionCount = 1;

   MessageBox.Show("Date they start: " + completionCalendar);

        }
```

I'm just looking for a nice and simple /dd/mm/yyyy or even dd-mm-yyyy etc any help please?

Comment: Try to use var data = completionCalendar.SelectionStart.ToString("dd-mm-yyyy");

Comment: try looking at the `completionCalendar.SelectedDate.ToString()`  this should do it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the above

```
   private void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        MessageBox.Show("Date they start: " + completionCalendar.SelectionEnd.ToString("dd-mm-yyyy"));

    }
```